# IOS WKwebview evaluatejavascript completion handler code not executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have this code.

```
 [webView evaluateJavaScript:    (@"document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()")     completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error){
  NSLog(@"CompletitionHandler");
  NSLog(@"%s", result);
}];
```

The NSLog lines are not executed.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: The only scenario I can think of for that happening, is `webView` being nil.

Comment: Is not nil because the page is displayed.

Comment: At which point in time are you executed the code from the question?